# Force most compilation to a remote host with distcc

Tags: distributed-computing

The distcc FAQ states that there is currently no scheme for balancing or prioritizing hosts. They recommend to simply list the fastest host on top or the list.

The situation here is that the remote host is a lot more powerful than the host where I'm compiling.

Would it be effective to simply list the same host several times in `/etc/distcc/hosts` in order to force most compilation tasks to the remote host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but do not include `localhost` in host list.

> As a general rule, if the aggregate CPU speed of the client is less than one fifth of the total, then the client should be left out of the list.

Also, distcc only distributes compilation, so preprocessing and linking will always be run locally.

[Reference](http://linux.die.net/man/1/distcc)

Comment: This answer is a bit dated. Maybe someone should update it. `distcc` can, at least according to its [documentation](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/distcc-pump.1.html), preprocess remotely using `distcc pump`. Linking is done locally, of course, still.